# How to extract the directory name from a Git repository URL?

Tags: python, git, url, directory, clone

I need to get the directory name that Git would use for cloning a repo from the repo's URL, in Python. E.g.

```
git@github.com:foo/bar.git -> bar
```

I've tried using a regex:

```
>>> url = 'git@github.com:foo/bar.git'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'^.*/(.*?)(\.git)?$', r'\1', url)
'bar'
```

Is there a better solution? I need to support both SSH and HTTPS URLs.

Comment: can you provide some examples of the https and ssh urls, and what is wrong w/what you have?

Comment: HTTPS urls generally look like this: `https://github.com/foo/bar.git `(with or without the `.git` extension). My approach seems to work, I'm just wondering if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: or `url.strip(".git").split("/")[-1]`, which I think looks a bit cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You could split your url on slashes, then take the last entry without the last 4 characters

```
url.split("/")[-1][:-4]
```

Comment: what if the path doesn't contain `.git`?

Comment: @planetp - You could easily use `.endswith` but i assumed in this case that wasn't something you were having to worry about

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the most robust version:

```
>>> url
'git@github.com:foo/bar.git'
>>> url.rstrip('/').rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[-1].removesuffix('.git')
'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import posixpath as path
>>> path.splitext(path.split('https://github.com/foo/bar.git')[1])[0]
'bar'
>>> path.splitext(path.split('git@github.com:foo/bar.git')[1])[0]
'bar'
```